# Bayesian MCMC inference with more free parameters than data points

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, degrees-of-freedom

I've come across Bayesian inference analysis with models that include more free parameters than observed data points (even up to three times more).

It is my understanding that although Bayesian MCMC is able to handle this seemingly very degenerate models, it does so by relying *heavily* on the priors.

Is this true? Are there any published articles one could use as reference (and learn more) about this issue?

Comment: Is your question about i) the ability of general Bayesian inference to provide answers when there are more parameters than data, or ii) the ability of MCMC algorithms to facilitate this inference?

Comment: My understanding was that this could only be done thanks to the use of priors in Bayesian inference. My mention of MCMC is because that's how I've always seen Bayesian inference done: through MCMC. I guess my original question is about your point i), but now I'm also interested about ii).

Comment: I don't have a good answer for you, but which models did you come across with many more free parameters than observed data points? Maybe a starting point to investigate would be to look into [hierarchical Bayesian models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_hierarchical_modeling)?

Comment: I work with stellar clusters. I've come across a model that, for each star, assigns three free parameters to the model. So the model effectively has 3N free parameters, for N observed points.